# LeNet5 "symmetry breaking" step, is (was) it important?

Tags: conv-neural-network, regularization

Reading through Yann LeCun's [original paper on LeNet5](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-01a.pdf), I have come across something that I haven't seen before in convolutional neural network architectures.  (Maybe that's just because I'm late to the party.) 
 Table I on page 8 shows that the connections between layers S2 and C3 are deliberately incomplete.  The authors state that this incomplete connection serves two purposes:

1) To reduce the size of the tensor being passed between these layers (obviously a more pressing concern in 1998 than today), and

2) To "break symmetry" in the model, forcing different and complimentary connections between the features in these two layers.

I have looked at several web pages where people implement what they call "LeNet5", and none of them seem to bother with this symmetry-breaking step.  It could be a bit challenging to implement with standard CNN software such as Keras, freezing only some of the weights and allowing others to vary.  None of the more modern CNN visual processing architectures I have examined (AlexNet, Inception, etc.) seem to bother with symmetry-breaking either.

Symmetry-breaking vaguely resembles a regularization technique, at least to me.  Once we get to using dropout or batch normalization, are we effectively accomplishing the same goal as symmetry-breaking by different means?

Answer (score 1):

> More importantly, it forces a break of symmetry in the network. Different feature maps are forced to extract different hopefully complementary, features because they get different sets of inputs.

As you quoted, symmetry breaking is a way to *force different feature extraction*. Another way to do this is randomly initializing the weights of a NN. Since all your hidden units will not have the same weights initially, there are good chances of them converging via different paths to different final values. You will find this [explanation here interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20029817). As this answer says, the random initialization of the weights will achieve the symmetry breaking objective, and that's the reason we didn't see this issue in AlexNet, Inception etc.

To further answer your question on using dropout, batch normalization– yes they are a way of introducing randomizations in your network and hence they should suffice.
[see the comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027598/why-should-weights-of-neural-networks-be-initialized-to-random-numbers/20029817#comment63739231_20029817)

Comment: Welcome to [Stats.SE]. Thank you for your answer. Can you please edit you answer to expand it, in order to include the main points of the link you provide? It will be more helpful both for people searching in this site and in case the link breaks. By the way, see some tips on [answer], on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Thanks @Ertxiem, I've updated the answer

Comment: one should be dubious about the supposed "explanations" in most neural networks research.  In any case, Lenet5 was certainly randomly initialised as are all(?) neural nets.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your implementation question, you could add a linear layer with identity activation and initialize the weights as zeros or ones as you wish (i.e. the layer is a binary mask). This layer should be fixed (i.e. not trained).

You can initialize the mask however you wish to achieve the desired wiring.